# Firefox loads google searches quickly, but website loading is slow

Tags: firefox

I'm brand new to Linux and Ubuntu and I have this issue on both my laptop and desktop, both run Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. When I run a speedtest it shows that I get 250Mbs+ but websites take forever to load. When I switch to Windows 10 everything is back to normal. Suggestions?

Update: I tried Chromium and it's lightning quick. So it is definitely a Firefox problem.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to other browsers, Firefox may use its own Connection Settings (in preferences - Network Settings). There are 4 possible choices: No proxy, Auto-detect, system proxy and manual proxy. Since your Chromium browser works fine, I am sure the problem is there.